# Monero on Tails OS - Connection Errors Download Node

Tags: full-node, tor

I am trying to run the Monero wallet in Tails using the [Guide to creating a Monero GUI wallet in Tails](https://medium.com/@_Bosch_/sheeps-noob-guide-to-monero-gui-in-tails-3-2-d75c4e829c17).
I run the following iptables command from within the extracted Monero wallet:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT
[sudo] password for amnesia:
```

But the command does't return anything. So I'm not sure if the port has been opened through Tails' firewall. I then run command.

```
DNS_PUBLIC=tcp torsocks ./monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --data-dir /media/amnesia/monero
```

The node begins to download.

```
2020-04-03 17:14:50.538 I Monero 'Carbon Chamaeleon' (v0.15.0.1-release)
2020-04-03 17:14:50.538 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2020-04-03 17:14:50.538 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2020-04-03 17:14:50.538 I Initializing core...
2020-04-03 17:14:50.538 I Loading blockchain from folder /media/amnesia/monero/lmdb ...
2020-04-03 17:14:50.579 I Loading checkpoints
```

I get a few errors.

```
2020-04-03 19:19:26.124 I Synced 46512/2068842 (2%, 2022330 left)
1585941567 ERROR torsocks[16670]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
2020-04-03 19:19:28.302 I Synced 46612/2068842 (2%, 2022230 left)
```

But the node continues to download regardless. It always reaches 18% before I get this error.

```
2020-04-03 19:52:46.631 I Synced 386060/2068853 (18%, 1682793 left)
2020-04-03 17:48:47.173 W Failed to commit a transaction to the db: Input/output error
2020-04-03 17:48:47.173 E Exception in cleanup_handle_incoming_blocks: Failed to commit a transaction to the db: Input/output error
1585936393 ERROR torsocks[13066]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
1585936460 ERROR torsocks[13066]: Connection timed out (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:547)
1585936582 ERROR torsocks[13066]: Connection refused to Tor SOCKS (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:543)
1585936684 ERROR torsocks[13066]: Connection timed out (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:547)
1585937052 ERROR torsocks[13066]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
1585937937 ERROR torsocks[13066]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
2020-04-03 18:18:57.415 W No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 18080
1585938270 ERROR torsocks[13066]: Connection timed out (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:547)
```

If the problem is indeed this.

```
2020-04-03 18:18:57.415 W No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 18080
```

I dont understand because I have already opened port 18080 on my dlink router.
[image: Port Forwarding]

And I've also tried using a virtual server on the router:
[image: Virtual Server]

I'm not sure where the problem lies. Using the latest Tails OS and Monero Wallet. Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need incoming connections to sync. Downloading the blockchain over tor is a serious bottleneck.

Comment: I always just get to 18% using the terminal to download the blockchain but then I get these errors. The Tails Monero GUI just sits at 'waiting for daemon to sync' with no activity. What do you suggest I do otherwise to get the blockchain?

Comment: Just run monerod on clearnet.. When it's finished syncing, do the tor thingy from there..

Comment: How do I run monerod on clearnet from Tails? Or do I have to do that outside of Tails and then move that over to Tails?

Comment: If tails is TOR only (IDK) run monerod on something that's not TOR. Make your --data-dir point to a location (external SSD) that you can use when launching Tails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, is that I formatted the SD card with FAT32 (same as Tails OS) and the download would max out at 4GBs oops. I used Linux's file system and had no problems. Can someone recommend a Bitcoin to Monero exchange i can use?